# Loop audio file without gap

Tags: android, audio, android-mediaplayer, mobile-application

I'm using `MediaPlayer` on Android to play audio files. Looping on low end devices causes a very clear stutter in the sound at the end of the file. I can imagine a seamless playback by playing another instance of `MediaPlayer` before the previous one ends with some fade effects. Is there no easier way to achieve seamless looping playback of audio?

Comment: Yes, gapless looping of a single file is implemented the same way as gapless playback of two files. But I'm curious why would you need a fade out -- IMO this is defeating the purpose of gapless playback, since it reveals the moment when the playback starts over.

Comment: Let me clarify. The gapless playback doesn't appear quite gapless on low end device at least. Thus I'm implementing a solution where I start playback of the same file (new instance) a few seconds before the original instance ends and fade in the new instance. This provides more of a gapless playback. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Depending on your application `AudioTrack.setLoopPoints` may be used for looped playback.